# Python 3.9.0 doesn't print colored text in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, colors, ansi-escape

I'm having trouble printing colored text on the terminal in both `\x1b` and `\033` methods. When I was using Python version 3.7.4 it was working perfectly. Would someone be using version 3.9.0 and is managing to print colored texts on the terminal?

[image]

Comment: You are using python console, and not a terminal. Did you have the same results in terminal (so running a script non-interactively?). The problem could also be in the terminal. You just uses codes which are specific for some terminals. Did you check that terminal has the required capabilities, and the codes are correct for your terminal?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The console on officel Python website uses the ```3.8.0``` version https://i.imgur.com/fa6WknW.png and it's working on.

Answer (score 0):

Output your code to external terminal if you working with some IDE. In the settings can usually be option to output dedicated programs to external terminal.

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

```py
from os import system

Lime = '\33[92m'
CD = '\033[0m'

system("")

info = Lime + "[INFO]" + CD
print(info)
```

[Click to show -> Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds3Hn.png)

### Output --->

[Click to show -> Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBquB.png)

#### try Method 2

## TRY :

###### Install Colored Text

```sh
 git clone https://github.com/L45T500TH4CCK/PythonColoredText.git
```

##### github page --> https://github.com/L45T500TH4CCK/PythonColoredText

###### Use

```py
  
from (Your_colorText_Path).colorText import colors

print(colors.Yellow + " Account ID: " + colors.CD + colors.Lime + "12312" + colors.CD)
```